# Blur effect not properly adjusted to parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have cell with imageView and I wanted to blur this image to hide it for the user. To do this I just added a blur view on it, but it's not properly adjusted and there is a white stripe on the right edge. Do you have any idea what is happening with that? This problem is only appears on physical devices, on simulator it's just fine. This is my code for blur view.

This is how it currently looks like: [image: Image with problem]

```
#import "BlurView.h"

@interface BlurView()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView;
@end

@implementation BlurView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    self.blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    self.blurEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:self.blurEffectView];

    [[self.blurEffectView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.widthAnchor] setActive:YES];
    [[self.blurEffectView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.heightAnchor] setActive: YES];
    [[self.blurEffectView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor] setActive:YES];
    [[self.blurEffectView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerYAnchor] setActive:YES];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: From what I can tell your constraints are acceptable and the blur view looks like it is extending to the view edges. Is your image view stretching the image content to the edges? What is your image view's content mode set to?

Comment: Show the code for adding this view. Looks like you do not add constraints for the `BlurView` itself.

Comment: It looks that in my code I have switched on `shouldRasterize` property and this was main problem. When I switch it off everything looks ok now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all my recommendation is that you should always try to use storyboards and apply constraints there (so you don't have this kind of issues).

If you must do it programmatically can you try applying the blur on layoutSubviews method?

```
-(void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

//    your code here.

}
```

As Apple says (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews): You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want.

Hope it helps.